# What is Arch Fallback in Arch boot menu?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, boot

What is exactly "Arch Fallback" in the **Arch** boot menu?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Arch Wiki mkinitcpio page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio#Image_creation_and_activation) explains the difference between the two:

> The fallback image utilizes the same configuration file as the default image, except the autodetect hook is skipped during creation, thus including a full range of modules. The autodetect hook detects required modules and tailors the image for specific hardware, shrinking the initramfs.

You can create your own image by using the `-c` and `-g` options to `mkinitcpio` - this is helpful if you want to test your own images (to, for example, remove uneeded hooks), like so:

```
sudo mkinitcpio -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf.new -g /boot/linux-new.img
```

Answer (score 7):

From [this post in the Arch Linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=72344) (edited for readability):

> 1) The kernel on arch is just one (i.e. there's no fallback kernel)
>
> 2) What's 'fallback' is the initramfs (the stuff that loads just after the kernel when you boot)
>
> 3) The difference is that the "normal" initramfs contains only the stuff that you configured to be there (`/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`) and the "fallback" contains the default selection of drivers (eg all filesystem drivers, etc..)

So (as noted in a comment) it's an initramfs that loads everything. The kernel is the same.

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted that. The "fallback" initrd is built without the autodetect hook, and therefore includes everything--just the opposite of minimal... See [the mkinitcpio page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mkinitcpio#Image_creation_and_activation)

Comment: Indeed. Editing my answer to fix that